# Mutiplas conexões websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Eu tenho um script que faz 4 ou 10 conexões com um jogo depois que eu clico no botão 'run bots', eu tentei criar um botão 'run bots2' para criar mais 4/10 conexões com o sevidor mas sem encerrar as primeiras mas sempre as primeiras são fechadas

Eu não quero simplesmente mudar o numero 4 pra 8 nem o 10 pra 20, quero criar outro botão para abrir mais conexões com o mesmo servidor...

Obs: Se o #token tiver mais que 0 caracteres porém menos que 8 o limite de conexões do mesmo IP com o servidor é 4 e se o #token tiver 0 exatos caracteres o limite de conexões é 10

Minha ideia é fazer as 4/10 conexões e depois usar um proxy para mudar meu IP e fazer mais conexões.

Alguém me da essa luz ?

script completo: http://pastebin.com/SiT0Av5T

Provavelmente é aqui que precisa mexer:

```
            var _0xd9f3 = ["runBots", "length", "val", "#token", "You must to create a Party first or connect to a private server.", "Stop bots", "html", "[data-itr='run_bots']", "onclick", "stopBots(); return false;", "attr", "push", "binaryType", "arraybuffer", "bot", "id", "onopen", "setUint8", "setUint32", "buffer", "send", "charCodeAt", "onmessage", "#botsNick", "setNick", "[name='botsFollow']:checked", "mouse", "x", "y", "setDirection", "onclose", "splice", "onerror", "undefined", "setUint16", "setInt32"];
            d[_0xd9f3[0]] = function(e, t) {
                if (jQuery(_0xd9f3[3])[_0xd9f3[2]]()[_0xd9f3[1]] > 8) return alert(_0xd9f3[4]), !1;
                for (mAB = jQuery(_0xd9f3[3])[_0xd9f3[2]]()[_0xd9f3[1]] > 0 ? 4 : 10, jQuery(_0xd9f3[7])[_0xd9f3[6]](_0xd9f3[5]), jQuery(_0xd9f3[7])[_0xd9f3[10]](_0xd9f3[8], _0xd9f3[9]), bots = [], currentServer = e, i = 0; i < mAB; i++) bots[_0xd9f3[11]](new WebSocket(e)), bots[i][_0xd9f3[12]] = _0xd9f3[13], bots[i][_0xd9f3[14]] = i, bots[i][_0xd9f3[15]] = null, bots[i][_0xd9f3[16]] = function() {
                    a = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(5)), a[_0xd9f3[17]](0, 254), a[_0xd9f3[18]](1, 5, !0), this[_0xd9f3[20]](a[_0xd9f3[19]]), a = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(5)), a[_0xd9f3[17]](0, 255), a[_0xd9f3[18]](1, 154669603, !0), this[_0xd9f3[20]](a[_0xd9f3[19]]), a = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(1 + t[_0xd9f3[1]])), a[_0xd9f3[17]](0, 80);
                    for (var e = 0; e < t[_0xd9f3[1]]; ++e) a[_0xd9f3[17]](e + 1, t[_0xd9f3[21]](e));
                    this[_0xd9f3[20]](a[_0xd9f3[19]])
                }, bots[i][_0xd9f3[22]] = function() {
                    playing() && (this[_0xd9f3[24]](jQuery(_0xd9f3[23])[_0xd9f3[2]]()), xx = jQuery(_0xd9f3[25])[_0xd9f3[2]]() == _0xd9f3[26] ? sa : localStorage[_0xd9f3[27]], yy = jQuery(_0xd9f3[25])[_0xd9f3[2]]() == _0xd9f3[26] ? ta : localStorage[_0xd9f3[28]], this[_0xd9f3[29]](xx, yy))
                }, bots[i][_0xd9f3[30]] = function() {
                    bots[_0xd9f3[31]](this[_0xd9f3[14]], 1)
                }, bots[i][_0xd9f3[32]] = function() {
                    bots[_0xd9f3[31]](this[_0xd9f3[14]], 1)
                }, bots[i][_0xd9f3[24]] = function(e) {
                    if (typeof bots[this[_0xd9f3[14]]] == _0xd9f3[33]) return !1;
                    var t = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(1 + 2 * e[_0xd9f3[1]]));
                    t[_0xd9f3[17]](0, 0);
                    for (var a = 0; a < e[_0xd9f3[1]]; ++a) t[_0xd9f3[34]](1 + 2 * a, e[_0xd9f3[21]](a), !0);
                    bots[this[_0xd9f3[14]]][_0xd9f3[20]](t[_0xd9f3[19]])
                }, bots[i][_0xd9f3[29]] = function(e, t) {
                    return typeof bots[this[_0xd9f3[14]]] == _0xd9f3[33] ? !1 : (a = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(13)), a[_0xd9f3[17]](0, 16), a[_0xd9f3[35]](1, e, !0), a[_0xd9f3[35]](5, t, !0), a[_0xd9f3[18]](9, 0, !0), void bots[this[_0xd9f3[14]]][_0xd9f3[20]](a[_0xd9f3[19]]))
                }
            }
```

Lembrando também que esse é o botão:

```
<button onclick="runBots(jQuery('#serverIP').val(), jQuery('#token').val()); return false;" class="btn btn-default btn-runBots" data-itr="run_bots"></button>
```